# React native share content like TikTok profile page share

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building my startup app with react native, I want to achieve the feature to share content like profile page in my app, just like sharing TikTok profile page with the link of the profile page. How can I achieve that?

I have gone through some tutorials online but they were majorly sharing image not content. I want to be able to share my profile page with profile page link and the users profile picture just like TikTok. Please any help on how to achieve that will so appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Marlon-Paulo-da-Silva/TikTok-Clone-ReactNative)

Comment: @Rohit the repo you shared did not solve my problem. I mean, I want the code on how to share profile page content. And I used TikTok as a case study.